# Are "close" and "open" verbs or adjectives?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, parts-of-speech

I'm really hard stuck trying to comprehend whether these two words simultaneously have two natures.

I read:

- The door is **open**
- The door is **opened**

Difference?

- The door is **close**
- The door is **closed**

Difference?

Comment: Review this and see if that helps: [Opened vs open?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/141547/191178)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The door is open" indicates that someone may go through. An adjective.

"The door is opened" This is better written as, "The door was opened." It means the door that was closed is closed no longer. A verb.

"The door is close" This means the door is nearby, and its status of opened or closed is not the aim of the phrase. An adverb.

"The door is closed" This indicates that the door needs to be opened to go through it. A verb.

Answer (score 2):

*Close*  (pronounced /kloz/, the same as *clothes*) and *open* are verbs, or at least can be used as verbs in many constructions. The word also spelled *close* but pronounced /klos/ is an adjective, often appearing with the preposition *to*. *Open* (same pronunciation as the verb) can also be an adjective.

- *This store will open at 9 and close* /kloz/ *at 19*.
- *This store is not very close* /klos/ *to his home, but it's open now.*

Since they can be verbs, they can have past participles: *closed* and *opened*; these can also function as adjectives.

- *The store is closed* /klozd/ *until tomorrow.*
- *It's a closed* /klozd/ *store.*
- *You shouldn't leave an opened* /'opənd/ *jar out.* (*open* is also OK here)

So, yes, they are verbs, **and** yes, they are adjectives.
And who ever told you they had to be one or the other?